# Checking Function Type in Scala

Tags: scala

In Haskell, I can check a function's type in `ghci` by using `:t`:

```
Prelude> :t odd
odd :: Integral a => a -> Bool
```

This says that the function `odd` takes an `Integral` type and returns a `Bool`. Is there something similar for Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually the exact same in the Scala REPL:

```
scala> def odd(x : Int) = x % 2 != 0
odd: (x: Int)Boolean

scala> :t odd
(x: Int)Boolean
```

Comment: Was this added recently? I don't see it in scala 2.8.1.

Comment: @VladtheImpala REPL is constantly evolving.

Comment: @VladtheImpala I was confused for the same reason; it's not in scala 2.8.1 but it _is_ in scala 2.9.1. HTH